# Entity framework load entities from XML

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, xsd

I am using an XML and an XSD provided by another company to generate my model classes with XSD.exe, and I need to deserialize my XML and add the created entity to EF.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));

FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\Test\my.xml", FileMode.Open);
Model data = (Model)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

using (DatabaseContext ent = new DatabaseContext())
{
    ent.Model.Add(data);
    ent.SaveChanges();
}
```

The XML looks about like this:

```
<Model>
  <Entry id="1">
    <DataSource id="x">
    </DataSource>
  </Entry>
  <Entry id="2">
    <DataSource id = "x">
    </DataSource>
  </Entry>
<Model>
```

DataSources and Entries can be included in the given XML multiple times with the same ID (Primary Key), which results in a primary key exception when saving the changes. I cannot change the file, so I have to set my code up in a way that makes EF understand to add a datasource only once, and keep the relations in the hierarchie intact.

I tried to use the ObjectStateManager and the ObjectStateManagerChanged event to get a hold on each entity when it gets added to the context. But I could not find a way to get around the primary key issue. Can you please help me and point me in the right direction?

Edit: Just to clarify, I will only have one Model entity in my file, so when adding it it won't be there for sure. But the related entities, like datasources and entries might occur multiple times in the file and will be deserialzed as provided.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: well, you know you can't have duplicate primary keys, so what do you want to happen?  That's not an EF issue, but rather a database requirement.

Comment: Why do you want to store entities as XML in your database? Sounds very fishy/dangerous.

Comment: @ Bas Brekelmans: No I don't store entities as XML in my database. I use an XML file I receive from a webservice, and want to save that data into my db the way I described.

Comment: @Jonesy: The file will contain the same datasource multiple times. How can I prevent them to be added to my context multiple times? I have a DataSource table, so I want to reuse the datasources of course.

Comment: check if it's already added, something like `if(!ent.Model.Any(m => m.id ==data.id) { ...add it... };`

Comment: The thing is, that I only deserialize one big model entity (essentially the whole file), which has references to Entries and DataSources, and add that whole package to the context in one step. I don't have control over all the related other entities involved, they will all get addded automaticalle atm, also the duplicates. Maybe my approach is wrong in general?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that my model was not correct in the first place, and a few changes did the trick.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: This is not an answer.